# как пользоваться библиотекой audioop?

Tags: python, аудио

Не могу найти сайт на котором нормально учат пользоваться библиотекой audioop, поделитесь ссылочкой пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Официальная документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/audioop.html) в помощь

Comment: Хоть кто то нормально отвечает на мои вопросы!!!